# Noise texture weird on imported houdini mesh

Tags: texturing

The only thing I've done is plug in a noise texture, I've never seen this before. Maybe I have to clear some specific attribute from houdini?
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see the topology of some of your imported mesh, please?

Comment: I added a new photo of it

Comment: Cheers. Looks OK, doesn't it? Maybe share a representative  chunk of your mesh in  a .blend  on https://blend-exchange.com/  . Try eliminating any Custom Normals that may exist on the mesh? : https://imgur.com/0N0fBaN

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2PyRZJGb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2PyRZJGb/)

Comment: I basically just did some ocean spectrums into an ocean evaluate, so its kind of just a plane.

Comment: Thanks for the file .. it'll be tomorrow before I can have a look... Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, without explicit instruction, a Blender 3D-type texture is mapped in 'Generated' texture space.

Generated space measures 0-1 along all the sides of an object's bounding-box, oriented to the object's axes.

Your (Y-up) ocean is very large in Object X and Z, relative to Y. This means, at shading-time, when calculating *Noise* values at vertices, and making the [barycentric interpolation](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates.html) of those values across rendered triangles, in Generated coordinates, dXZ/dU and dXZ/dV are small enough to run into the limits of floating-point resolution. The interpolation is aliased.

You can give the *Noise* calculation more to get its teeth into by mapping in 'Object' space instead:

[image]